# Meteor Full Calendar events array from Collection not rendering

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor, fullcalendar

I'm having an issue with Meteor and a FullCalendar package (rzymek:fullcalendar) where if I define an array of events directly it shows the events but if I get them from my Collection it doesn't even populate the array even though the Find method works in the console and shows me my events (the events array shows as empty in the console).
I did not remove the autopublish or insecure packages: this is a basic test.

main.js file:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function() {
        if (Meetings.find().count() === 0) {
            Meetings.insert({
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2015-02-06'
            });
        }
    });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
/* //this array of events shows if uncommented
        events = [
            {
            title: 'reuni',
            start: '2015-02-06'
            }
            ]*/
    Template.calendar.helpers({
        options: function() {
            return {
                events: events
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My collection.js file (inside a lib folder):

```
Meetings = new Mongo.Collection('meetings');

events = Meetings.find({}, {fields: {_id:0} }).fetch();  /*This will only show an empty array and not the events array that I fetch*/
```

Comment: Do you have autopublish in the application?

Comment: Yes. I was testing with autopublish as described

Answer (score 0):

Events get's set right after the collection is set.  Since you're saving it simply as an array there is no future query that is happening.

Try something like

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.calendar.helpers({
    options: function() {
      var events = [];
      Meetings.find().forEach(function(m){
        events.push( 
           // build object with needed properties here
        );
      });
      return {
          events: events;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Basically you need the find function inside the helper, or called inside the computation for that helper.  Leaving it outside in the global definition area remove's all re-activity from it.

Comment: I had tried that before with a simple Meetings.find({}).fetch() and it also doesn't work. No events are loaded. In fact by using {fields: {_id:0} }, Meteor doens't let it run:  Exception in template helper: Error: You may not observe a cursor with {fields: {_id: 0}}

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that.